# Is there a proper alternative for "work-stream"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In referring to components of a large project, the terms work-stream, or work stream are often used in business.  Is there a better or alternative phrase for expressing this concept?

Comment: From what I saw here for [*work stream*](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/work-stream.html), I would use *phases of the project* instead. But  [*work-stream*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/workstream) as such is well-defined. Why do you need a different phrase?

Comment: You are correct, work-stream, and work stream, are well defined and commonly used.  Workstream, is not most English dictionaries or spell-checkers.  I was looking for an alternative, or more elegant, term to indicate phases of a project the occur simultaneously.

Comment: I think that if you do some reading about project management, you will absorb some helpful terminology, such as *project lifespan*, *project life cycle*, and *phases*.  By the way, it's not clear to me from your question whether you want a word for the components or for the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

***Workflow*** is probably a more common term. According to [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/workflow),

> *noun* The sequence of industrial, administrative, or other processes through which a piece of work passes from initiation to completion.

Answer (score 0):

workstream is not hyphenated, and according to the Business Dictionary:The progressive completion of tasks completed by different groups within a company which are required to finish a single project. For example, the work stream for a manufacturing facility may include engineering, drafting, procurement, fabrication, quality control and shipping.

Workflow is the sequence of industrial, administrative, or other processes through which a piece of work passes from initiation to completion.

There doesn't appear to be a 'more correct' word other than these two

Comment: Welcome to ELU. If you can find the time, do check out our FAQ, ["How to answer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to help you post great answers. :)